# Invalid syntax when running Python script from Command Prompt

Tags: python

Edit: Python version 3.3.

I've got a Python script I'd like to run. I've added my Python/Scripts folder to the PATH, and so I open CMD and type:

```
python example.py
```

I think here's the best point to put some of the code:

```
while True:
    posts = user.get_submitted(limit=500) 

    print '[*] Posts' # this is line 18 
    for thing in posts:
        if thing.id in seen:
            continue
```

These are lines 15 to 18, and when trying to run the script I get the following error:

```
File "example.py", line 18
  print '[*] Posts'
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't see what the issue with the syntax is here, could someone please enlighten me to it?

Comment: What is your Python version?

Comment: Python 3? Python 2? Are you sure that there is nothing before line 18 missing a closing `)` or `]` or `}`?

Comment: Please fix your indentation here as well, since the `while True:` is at the same level as its body.

Comment: Sorry, it's Python version 3.3.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using Python 3. If that's the case, `print` requires parentheses:

```
print('[*] Posts')
```